# Is it possible to refresh stale elements?

Tags: htmlelements

I have a search page that contains a table that gets populated with search results after the user presses the search button. The page object wraps the rows of the search results table in a custom `HtmlElement` class.

I'm getting a stale element exception when accessing the results table - as you'd expect because it was just refreshed by an ajax request.

I've worked around it by returning a new instance of the page object after performing the search but I'd rather just recreate the search results field. Is there any way to do this?

Example:

```java
@FindBy(css = "[data-viewid='Table1'] .dojoxGridRow")
List<ActivityPerformanceRow> results;

// ...

public void search() {
    search.click()
    waitForAjaxToComplete();

    // If it was a standard WebElement list I'd do something like this:
    results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(
                      "[data-viewid='Table1'] .dojoxGridRow"));
}
```

Comment: Which element locator you use when initialize PageObject? By default AjaxElementLocator used, so no problem with stale elements since performs element search on every element access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing around I came up with this solution - it works well but doesn't deal with HtmlElement name property.  Given I don't use it that I'm aware of I'm ignoring it for now...

```
public <T extends HtmlElement> List<T> findElements(Class<T> elementClass, By by) {
    List<T> elements = new LinkedList<T>();

    for (WebElement element : driver.findElements(by)) {
        elements.add(HtmlElementLoader.createHtmlElement(elementClass, element, null));
    }

    return elements;
}
```